# How can one show that PA is equal to this?

Tags: logic, model-theory

In some class note, I have seen the alternative definition of PA which is given as following:

$$PA=\cup I \Sigma_n=\cup I\Pi_n$$

, while $I \Phi $ is Q equipped with the $\Phi$ induction axioms, given some class of formulas, $\Phi,$ given as below:
$$\bigl\{ A(0) \implies (\forall x)(A(S(x)) \implies (\forall x)A(x): A \in \Phi \bigl\} $$

How can I show that they are equivalent to each other?
In particular, how can I see $\cup I \Sigma_n = \cup I \Pi_n$?

Comment: Note that $\Sigma_n\subseteq\Pi_{n+1}$ and $\Pi_n\subseteq\Sigma_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! I can now see why it holds.